# How to get number of select queries made to a specific database for a duration (not whole mysql instance)?

Tags: mysql

I have a website running in shared hosting environment? I would like to know how many select queries are being run on database?

When I run the following query, I doubt that the result is for whole mysql instance through which the shared hosting is running. Because the difference in result when run with a minute difference is very huge. Definitely not what my website would get.

```
show global status like "Com_select"
```

How could I get the number of select queries made in a duration only for my database?

Comment: From WorkBench , client connections